# How to store EnumTypes with @AppStorage in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, appstorage

I want to store a map-status in `UserDefaults`. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
@AppStorage("myMapType") var mapType: MKMapType = .standard
```

Or do I have to access the rawValue of the `MKMapType` instead? How could I do this?

Comment: Use the rawValue

Comment: Ok. And how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct MapTypeSwitcherView: View {
    @AppStorage("myMapType") var mapType: Int = 0
    let mapCases: [MKMapType] = [.hybrid,.hybridFlyover, .mutedStandard,.satellite,.satelliteFlyover,.standard]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            MapViewUIKit()
            ForEach(mapCases, id: \.self ){ type in
                Button(type.rawValue.description, action: {
                    mapType = Int(type.rawValue)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MapViewUIKit: UIViewRepresentable {
    @AppStorage("myMapType") var mapType: Int = 0

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: UInt(mapType)) ?? .standard
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: UInt(mapType)) ?? .standard
    }
}
```

If it is a custom enumthat you can make conform to `Codable` it can be much simpler

```
enum MyValues: String, Codable, CaseIterable{
    case first
    case second
    case third
}
struct NewListView: View {
    @AppStorage("myEnumType") var enumType: MyValues = .first
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World!")
            Text(enumType.rawValue)
            Picker("myEnums", selection: $enumType, content: {
                ForEach(MyValues.allCases, id: \.self, content: { item in
                    Text(item.rawValue).tag(item)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the `String` conformance is needed. `Codable` and `CaseIterable` are not necessary on the enum used for an `@AppStorage` saved value. `String` already conforms to `Codable`.

Answer (score 11):

You can storing the following way:

```
@AppStorage("darkThemeOptionSelection") var darkThemeOptionSelection: DarkThemeOptions = .nord

enum DarkThemeOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case nord
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me with Picker selection ...

Comment: @aehlke Don't forget to add a tag using the chosen enum case on the `Text` used within the `pickerStyle`. The SwiftUI tag would be on this case:  `.tag(DarkThemeOptions.nord)`.  Do the same for all other cases of your picker for the selection to work.