# Storing Units in @AppStorage

Tags: swiftui, unit-conversion, appstorage

I need to store a user's chosen selection of 11 different measurement units in AppStorage.

Ideally something equivalent to:

`@AppStorage("shortDistance") var shortDistance: UnitLength = .meters`

I understand why this won't work, but need to do this as painlessly as possible as I need to access these in multiple places in my app. I need to be able to do various conversions on the units which are stored in CoreData as SI units.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: See 'How to store EnumTypes with @AppStorage in SwiftUI': https://stackoverflow.com/q/66399867/780291

Comment: Thank you. That’s certainly pointed me in the right direction.